# How to handle file saving data very often

Tags: c#, save, unity-game-engine

For know i am working with `BinaryFormatter` and `FileStream` because that is what was introduced in the unity tutorials.

What i want to achieve is saving data in local files quite often, could be every 5 seconds or so, so i thought i would try to find the best way to handle that.

Two possible solutions came to mind : 1/ create multiple saving files each for a certain area of data, so that i would only have to save as little data as possible when needed. 2/ saving modified data in part of a file without touching the rest.

Is 2/ possible ? if so, is it faster than just re-writing the whole file ?

Also, is it a good idea to keep a file open (via `File.Create` or something) and just `binaryFormatter.Serialize` when needed without closing the file ?

Comment: No, 2 is not possible, but that is not limited to the BinaryFormatter, that goes  for all other serializers as well. You have to write the whole stream. Keep in mind that the binaryformatter is rather strict in what it wants in the fileformat. Plan your versioning strategy with care or you might end up with data in files that you can't deserialize with the new version of the app.

Comment: Yes, i took that into consideration already, having a "version" embedded in the files and taking care of any retro-compatibility by update steps (well that is what i planned to do at least).

Comment: The binaryformatter is going to bite you then. Consider using the XmlSerializer, JSON or roll something your self.